# "IAM policy update failed. Request contains an invalid argument" when I create a service account in the Google API console

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-api-client

I'm adding a service account to my new Google API project at https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin, but when the service account is created it pops up with a message that says "IAM policy update failed. Request contains an invalid argument. Tracking number: c8529450008624799".

The service account actually gets created, but I don't have the ability to link it to my Google Play Console account. I've check that my Google Play Console account is an owner and followed all the steps in the tutorial. I even contacted Google Developer Support who said that the issue was out of their scope. Does anybody have any ideas on what could be causing this?